# Using the listChanged parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI plugin [fieldchooser](https://github.com/mateagar/fieldChooser) and I want to know whenever the list changes so that I can update it in the database.  The plugin has a listChanged function, but I'm not sure how to make it work.  I working off this example:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $sourceFields = $("#sourceFields");
            var $destinationFields = $("#destinationFields");
            var $chooser = $("#fieldChooser").fieldChooser(sourceFields, destinationFields);
        });
    </script>

    <div id="fieldChooser" tabIndex="1">
        <div id="sourceFields">
            <div>First name</div>
            <div>Last name</div>
            <div>Home</div>
            <div>Work</div>
            <div>Direct</div>
            <div>Cell</div>
            <div>Fax</div>
            <div>Work email</div>
            <div>Personal email</div>
            <div>Website</div>
        </div>
        <div id="destinationFields">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Elsewhere on stack overflow, I found this example:

```
    $chooser.on("listChanged",function(event,selection,list){
    //event <- The jQuery event invoking the callback.
    //selection <- The field (or set of fields) which has moved.
    //list <- The field list to which the selection has moved.
    alert("listChanged");
    }
```

and have tried this, without success:

```
$chooser.on("listChanged",function(mouseup,sourceFields,destinationFields){

alert("listChanged");
});
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions on making this work.  Thanks.

Comment: What errors do you see in console?

Comment: Was able to create a fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/v2Lrm9wq/ from this Demo: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Drag-Drop-Multi-Select-List-Box-fieldChooser/demo/

Comment: Found an issue with `var $chooser = $("#fieldChooser").fieldChooser(sourceFields, destinationFields);` as the varable names do not match.

Answer (score 1):

With correct code, this works as expected.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/v2Lrm9wq/2/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var $chooser = $("#fieldChooser").fieldChooser();
  var $sourceFields = $("#sourceFields").children();
  $chooser.getSourceList().add($sourceFields);
  $chooser.on("listChanged", function(event, selection, list) {
    alert("listChanged");
  });
});
```